# Angular 5: Unable to navigate to a dynamic url

Tags: javascript, angular, navigation, router

I was trying to navigate from a parent component (Core) using an url dynamically emitted from a child component (Menubar).
The problem is that the navigation is cancelled without any reason.

To find out if the problem came from the parent component, I implemented a button in the parent component navigating to a static url, and it worked!

Core template:

```
<app-menubar (onNavigation)="onMenubarNavigation($event)"></app-menubar>
<button type="button" (click)="navigate()">Navigate</button>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

Core component:

```
onMenubarNavigation(urlSegments: string[]): void {
    this.router.navigate(urlSegments);
  }

navigate(): void {
    let segments: string[];

    segments = ['index', 'messages'];
    this.router.navigate(segments);
  }
```

Menubar template:

```
<a (click)="changeRoute(element.module.route)">
// element.module route is the string: "/messages"
```

Menubar component:

```
@Output() onNavigation = new EventEmitter<string[]>(); 

changeRoute(url: string): void {
    let urlSegments: string[];

    urlSegments = url.split('/');
    urlSegments[0] = 'index';
    this.onNavigation.emit(urlSegments);
  }
```

App routing module:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: '.\/auth\/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  { path: 'logout', loadChildren: '.\/auth\/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './theme/core/app.core.module#AppCoreModule', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Core routing module:

```
    const coreRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppCoreComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: '..\/home\/app.home.module#AppHomeModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'index',
        loadChildren: '..\/index\/app.index.module#AppIndexModule'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'index',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(coreRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppCoreRoutingModule {}
```

The angular routing debug shows that both urls are the same during navigation, using the one emitted by the child component or the static one, but when I navigate using the one emitted, the navigation is cancelled and I have no idea why...

Has someone ever encoutered this kind of trouble with the angular router?

Comment: Can you post your router configuration (Array of route paths and components)?

Comment: @user2313300 I updated the post, let me know if you need more information

Comment: Short of having your entire project and being able to step through it with a debugger I don't think I can find what's wrong. If I had to guess, or at least start somewhere I'd try making the routes not lazy loaded, and instead loading all the child routes upfront just to see if that solves the problem and then work from there. Good luck, hope you figure it out!

Comment: @user2313300 I'll try working on a new basic project to run some test more easily. If I still trouble to make it work, I'll share the repo.